How do I add event description using Fullcalendar.io?
I'm currently creating an app using Flask and I have a calendar page with fullcalendar.io,  everything worked out well until I try to add descriptions to my events.
I've tried following this code
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: '2024-03-12',

    eventDidMount: function(info) {
      var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
        title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
      });
    },

    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        description: 'description for All Day Event',
        start: '2024-03-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        description: 'description for Long Event',
        start: '2024-03-07',
        end: '2024-03-10'
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        description: 'description for Repeating Event',
        start: '2024-03-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        description: 'description for Repeating Event',
        start: '2024-03-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        description: 'description for Conference',
        start: '2024-03-11',
        end: '2024-03-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        description: 'description for Meeting',
        start: '2024-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2024-03-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        description: 'description for Lunch',
        start: '2024-03-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        description: 'description for Meeting',
        start: '2024-03-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        description: 'description for Birthday Party',
        start: '2024-03-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        description: 'description for Click for Google',
        url: 'https://google.com/',
        start: '2024-03-28'
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});

the one written here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender and here stackoverflow question, but none of them worked.
Here's the code I wrote on my html, the one before I add the codes above:
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
      events: [
        {% for event in events %}
        {
          title : "{{ event.title }}",
          start : "{{ event.event_date }}",
          end : "{{ event.event_end }}",
          url: "{{url_for('post', id=event.id)}}"
        },
        {% endfor %}     
        {% for e in otherevents %}
        {
          title : "{{ e.title }}",
          start : "{{ e.start_date }}",
          end : "{{ e.end_date }}",
          color: '#CF9AE8'
        },
        {% endfor %}   
      ],
      eventColor: '#6574C4',
    },

    {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    }
          );
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>

Does anyone know what I should do? Thank you in advance!

You can use eventContent to define how the content is displayed inside the event blocks.
The description will be in arg.event.extendedProps.description.
Example adapted from the Content Injection documentation:
eventContent: function(arg) {
  let italicEl = document.createElement('i');
  italicEl.innerHTML = arg.event.extendedProps.description;

  let arrayOfDomNodes = [ italicEl ]
  return { domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes }
}

